# OpenSSH giving a "Failed to open file" error because it is looking for non existent -cert files

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh

I'm trying to log on to an ssh server from my Windows machine. When I enter the following command (where `rsa_key_file` is a private key generated using `ssh-keygen`):

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/rsa_key_file username@domain.edu -vvv`

I get an error saying that ssh was unable to open the non-existent file `rsa_key_file-cert`

```
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\usr/.ssh/config
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "domain.edu" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to domain.edu [128.91.223.80] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\usr/.ssh/rsa_key_file type 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/usr/.ssh/rsa_key_file-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/usr/.ssh/rsa_key_file-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\usr/.ssh/rsa_key_file-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug3: recv - from CB(2) ERROR:108, io:000002C78C7FE8F0
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset
```

My understanding is that ssh doesn't by default require that one has certificates verifying the keys, so I don't know why it is searching for certificate files.
My question is: if I don't want to use ssh with CA-generated certificates for the public key, how do I do this? I've used ssh before and I've never had to do this, setting the configuration `IdentitiesOnly yes` leads to the same problem.

Comment: Yes certs aren't required (or even common) but to simplify usage OpenSSH (including the Windows port) automatically looks and uses them if present and not if absent. Although labelled as 'error' this is actually ignored and has nothing to do with the subsequent failure of your connection.